# Replacement for showStatus() in JavaWebStart application

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm migrating an old legacy application from in browser applet to a `JFrame` based JWS application started via JNLP.
there is this one call to `AppletContext.showStatus(String status)` that I don't  know how to replace in a nice way.

I know that if I would still use the applet, I would still have the the faked `AppletContext` to use provided by the JNLP-API.
But as I drop the whole applet dependency I can not use this [Migrating Java Applets to Java Web Start and JNLP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/migrating-java-applets-jnlp.htm#JSDPG-GUID-1F95EBB3-D5CB-434A-B069-2261900738F5).

Is there any other simply way to have this for a frame based application without manually redoing it?

Comment: I have some bad news, Oracle looks set to deprecate JWS/JNLP as well (AFAIU). I would recommend rewriting the applet to a frame - so not the 'simple way'. Having said that, it is **possible** to write an applet context and applet stub that work in conjunction with a frame. The replacement of the `showStatus` method would have the context calling `setText` on a `JLabel` placed at the bottom of the frame.

Comment: As Thompson commented, beware that Oracle has seemed to announce the depreciation of WebStart technologies: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html

Comment: @BasilBourque: What? I read your link "... JNLP and Java Web Start including the javaws tool are all deprecated in JDK 9 and will be removed in a future release." but on the link I posted "Alternatives for applets and embedded JavaFX applications include Java Web Start and self-contained applications." these to sound contradicting ... both are related to JDK9 so ... what is true.

Comment: @PaulEdison Your link represents long-standing Oracle policy. My link is new, and bad news, apparently a break from that long-standing policy. But Oracle has made no formal announcement. I can find no discussion online.  Note that the ticket number `JDK-8184998` seen on my link is “not public”, with no further public documentation available. Quite a mystery.